# What is Milton Waddams' profession?

Tags: office-space

Is it ever stated what Milton Waddams' job is, in [*Office Space* (1999)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0151804/)?  All I can remember is his love of his stapler and that he was eventually relocated to the basement, but I can't recall if his job title/description is ever mentioned.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was exterminator and professional arsonist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Space) page:

> Peter Gibbons, a programmer at a company called Initech, is frustrated and unmotivated at his job. His co-workers include Samir Nagheenanajar and Michael Bolton, also programmers, and Milton Waddams, a meek collator who is mostly ignored by the rest of the office.

So Milton is a [Collator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation), which is:

> Collation is the assembly of written information into a standard order. Many systems of collation are based on numerical order or alphabetical order, or extensions and combinations thereof. Collation is a fundamental element of most office filing systems, library catalogs, and reference books.
>
> Collation differs from classification in that classification is concerned with arranging information into logical categories, while collation is concerned with the ordering of items of information, usually based on the form of their identifiers. Formally speaking, a collation method typically defines a total order on a set of possible identifiers, called sort keys, which consequently produces a total preorder on the set of items of information (items with the same identifier are not placed in any defined order).

[Or](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&newwindow=1&safe=off&client=firefox-b-ab&q=collates&oq=collates&gs_l=serp.3..0l2j0i10k1l8.6852.6852.0.8285.1.1.0.0.0.0.325.325.3-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.1.323.vR0ByFWJ0YM&gfe_rd=cr&ei=3GXRV-qUMYOp8weg7ae4DQ)

> collect and combine (texts, information, or sets of figures) in proper order.

Comment: This actually makes sense, since after you collate papers you staple (or clip) them together.  I've never worked anywhere in my 30 years of Corporate America where they had anyone dedicated to just collating.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - which is probably why they laid him off, no?